# React & Redux: how to update controlled input value on button click?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

So there is a controlled input field in my form. But I also want to update its value via button click. When button is clicked state gets updated, value has changed. But for some reason input's inner HTML is still the same.

What can be wrong? Maybe its because my form state is stored in Redux? By the way, I'm not using Redux Form or anything else, I just store my form state in Redux and that's it. Is that OK?

Code is like this. I use react-text-mask. 'address' is imported from the Redux state:

```
import MaskedInput from 'react-text-mask' 

<MaskedInput
      mask={mask}
      onChange={handleChange}
      type: 'text',
      name: 'address',
      value: address
    />
```

There is also one thing to mention. When I only press the button everything works perfectly fine. But after I have typed something in this field it stops working: right after that moment button click updates state but inner HTML no longer changes.

Comment: Provide your code  example please. Are you binding your input value to your input with a variable?

Comment: Code is provided.

Comment: do you use `connect` to connect the state and actions to your component ?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider bind value state of your component to input element

`<input value={value} onChange={e => handleCode} />`

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the reason. It's just a bug in react-text-mask package. Rolled back to the previous version and now it works!

This issue is also discussed here: https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/issues/806

Thanks everyone.